# How many times can firebase serve, the "currentUser.getIdToken() and verifyIdToken()" requests, for the particular user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have to verify current user server side, so I need to send Id token, every-time a user calls the server. Which means I need to generate the Id token every time on the client-side. So, does firebase has any limit on this, like generating and verifying the user based on the Id token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`verifyIdToken()` and `getIdToken()` are functionality offerings from Firebase Authentications.

Firebase Authentication is a [completely free service](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) (Except PhoneAuth), you are allowed to have as many users you want, thus there ain't a rate limiting for verifyIdToken. (For phone auth as well, the charges are only for initial authentication on client-side, not for id tokens)

Lastly there are [limits for API calls](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits), but way too generous for any project.

Comment: Thanx, that answers, my all doubts..:)